How set black text on Quill?
I was looking for a solution on the web, and it seems that there is one but I can't implement it, and the ia couldn't help me either. The editor lets me select any color except black, it just leaves it white. I leave you the code so that you can help me, if possible. Thank you.
<div id="divEditor">
    <!-- Editor Quill -->
    <div id="toolbar-container">
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-font"></select>
            <select class="ql-size"></select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-image"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold"></button>
            <button class="ql-italic"></button>
            <button class="ql-underline"></button>
            <button class="ql-strike"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-color"></select>
            <select class="ql-background"></select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
            <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-header">
                <option value="1"></option>
                <option value="2"></option>
                <option selected></option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-align"></select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-clean"></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="editor-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
            theme: 'snow',
            modules: {
                toolbar: '#toolbar-container',
            }
        });
</script>

